# Including .mp3 files in .apk

Tags: android, media-player

I'm currently working on Media Player. All is done except that i have .mp3 files in android emulator external storage. What i want to know is, how can i include all those .mp3 files to the .apk so that when i install the the app on phone, the files automatically transfer either on internal or external storage of the device.
I've gone through this issue but couldn't find best possible answer anywhere.

Please help me!

this is my code

**VoiceService.java**

```
package com.example.soundplayer;

import android.app.Service;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import com.example.soundplayer.Voice;

public class VoiceService extends Service implements
MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener{

    //media player
    private MediaPlayer player;
    //song list
    private ArrayList<Voice> songs;
    //current position
    private int songPosn;

    private boolean shuffle=false;

    private Random rand;

    private String songTitle;

    private static final int NOTIFY_ID=1;

    private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();

    public void onCreate()
    {
        //create the service
        super.onCreate();
        //initialize position
        songPosn=0;
        //create player
        player = new MediaPlayer();

        initMusicPlayer();

        rand=new Random();


    }
    public void setShuffle(){
          if(shuffle) shuffle=false;
          else shuffle=true;
        }

    public void initMusicPlayer()
    {
        player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
                  PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
                player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                player.setOnErrorListener(this);

    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<Voice> theSongs){
          songs=theSongs;
        }

    public class MusicBinder extends Binder 
    {
          VoiceService getService() {
            return VoiceService.this;
    }
        }


    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return musicBind;
    }
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
          player.stop();
          player.release();
          return false;
        }

    public void playSong(){
          //play a song

        player.reset();
        //get song
        Voice playSong = songs.get(songPosn);
        songTitle=playSong.getTitle();
        //get id
        long currSong = playSong.getID();
        //set uri
        Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
          android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
          currSong);
        try
        {
              player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
        }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
              Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
            }
            player.prepareAsync();
        }

    public void setSong(int songIndex){
          songPosn=songIndex;
        }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(player.getCurrentPosition()>=0){
            mp.reset();
            playNext();
          }

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
      stopForeground(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.reset();
          return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();

        Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
          notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendInt)
          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play)
          .setTicker(songTitle)
          .setOngoing(true)
          .setContentTitle("Playing")
          .setContentText(songTitle);
        Notification not = builder.build();

        startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, not);

    }

    public int getPosn(){
          return player.getCurrentPosition();
        }

        public int getDur(){
          return player.getDuration();
        }

        public boolean isPng(){
          return player.isPlaying();
        }

        public void pausePlayer(){
          player.pause();
        }

        public void seek(int posn){
          player.seekTo(posn);
        }

        public void go(){
          player.start();
        }

        public void playPrev(){
              songPosn--;
              if(songPosn>=0) songPosn=songs.size()-1;
              playSong();
            }

        public void playNext(){
            if(shuffle){
                int newSong = songPosn;
                while(newSong>=songPosn){
                  newSong=rand.nextInt(songs.size());
                }
                songPosn=newSong;
              }
              else{
                songPosn++;
                if(songPosn==songs.size()) songPosn=0;
              }
              playSong();
            }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.soundplayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

import android.widget.MediaController.MediaPlayerControl;

import com.example.soundplayer.VoiceService.MusicBinder;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayerControl{

    private ArrayList<Voice> songList;
    private ListView songView;
    private VoiceService musicSrv;
    private Intent playIntent;
    private boolean musicBound=false;
    private VoiceController controller;
    private boolean paused=false, playbackPaused=false;



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        songView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.song_list);

        songList = new ArrayList<Voice>();

        getSongList();

        Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Voice>(){
              public int compare(Voice a, Voice b){
                return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
              }
              });

        SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(this, songList);
        songView.setAdapter(songAdt);

        setController();


        }

    private void setController(){
          //set the controller up
        controller = new VoiceController(this);
        controller.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                playNext();
              }
            }, new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                playPrev();
              }
            });
        controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
        controller.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.song_list));
        controller.setEnabled(true);

        }

    private void playNext(){
        musicSrv.playNext();
          if(playbackPaused){
            setController();
            playbackPaused=false;
          }
          controller.show(0);
        }

        //play previous
        private void playPrev(){
            musicSrv.playPrev();
              if(playbackPaused){
                setController();
                playbackPaused=false;
              }
              controller.show(0);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPause(){
          super.onPause();
          paused=true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume(){
          super.onResume();
          if(paused){
            setController();
            paused=false;
          }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
          controller.hide();
          super.onStop();
        }


    //connect to the service
    private ServiceConnection musicConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

      @Override
      public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MusicBinder binder = (MusicBinder)service;
        //get service
        musicSrv = binder.getService();
        //pass list
        musicSrv.setList(songList);
        musicBound = true;
      }



      @Override
      public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        musicBound = false;
      }



    };

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    public void songPicked(View view){
         musicSrv.setSong(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()));
          musicSrv.playSong();
          if(playbackPaused){
            setController();
            playbackPaused=false;
          }
          controller.show(0);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      if(playIntent==null){
        playIntent = new Intent(this, VoiceService.class);
        bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(playIntent);
      }
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_shuffle:
              musicSrv.setShuffle();
              break;
        case R.id.action_end:
          stopService(playIntent);
          musicSrv=null;
          System.exit(0);
          break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
      stopService(playIntent);
      musicSrv=null;
      super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void getSongList() {

        ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);


        if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
              //get columns
              int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
              int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
              int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
              //add songs to list
              do {
                long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                songList.add(new Voice(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
              }
              while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
            }

        }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        musicSrv.go();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         playbackPaused=true;
          musicSrv.pausePlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        if(musicSrv!=null && musicBound && musicSrv.isPng())
            return musicSrv.getDur();
          else return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        if(musicSrv!=null && musicBound && musicSrv.isPng())

            return musicSrv.getPosn();
          else return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void seekTo(int pos) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        musicSrv.seek(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        if(musicSrv!=null && musicBound)
            return musicSrv.isPng();
          return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAudioSessionId() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }



}
```

Comment: You can put them on the res/raw folder and play them with :
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.mySong);

Comment: can i make options of storing the files in sd card when available in phone, and if not then directly into the internal storage?

Comment: you need to download that file

Comment: which fie do i have to download?

Comment: will an answer on copying file from assets to sd card will help you?

Comment: Yah, i mean some of the mobile doesn't have enough internal memory to store large number of audio files for the media player. That's y I'm eager to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

just copy your .mp3 files into res/raw folder and read them

```
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.fileName);
```

Comment: if in case i want to directly transfer the files in external memory(sd card) of the phone while installing, then how do i do it?

Comment: check this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583820/copy-files-inside-android-internal-memory